# How to restart numbering of Exerciselist?

Tags: numbering, exercises

I have problems with the `exercise` package. How can I make the second `Exerciselist` to start at one?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{exercise}



\title{xercise List Bug}
\author{Someone}


\begin{document}


\begin{ExerciseList}

%1
  \Exercise Prove that...

  \Answer From the definition....

\end{ExerciseList}

\begin{ExerciseList}

%2
  \Exercise Find an example of....
  \Answer It's well known....

\end{ExerciseList}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

The counter used by the `ExerciseList` environment is called `Exercise`.

Thus, if you put the line

```
\setcounter{Exercise}{0}
```

just before the second `ExerciseList` environment starts, you will achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{exercise}



\title{xercise List Bug}
\author{Someone}


\begin{document}


\begin{ExerciseList}

%1
  \Exercise Prove that...

  \Answer From the definition....

\end{ExerciseList}

\setcounter{Exercise}{0}

\begin{ExerciseList}

%2
  \Exercise Find an example of....
  \Answer It's well known....

\end{ExerciseList}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For occasional uses, [@karlkoeller's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142820#answer-143014) of using `\setcounter{Exercise}{0}` is perfectly good and is straightforward.  If you want to automate this so that the counter resets in every chapter or section of a document, the [chngcntr package](https://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr?lang=en) provides a convenient way of doing this.  Simply add the following to the document preamble.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{Exercise}{chapter}
```

The second argument to `\counterwithin*` can be any other counter, so you can use `section` or `subsection` to restart exercise numbers in every section or subsection.

Comment: There is no need to load `chngcntr` with recent versions of LaTeX, because `\counterwithin` and the other commands that the package used to provide are now in the kernel.